# converting value from dictionary to NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, type-conversion

I have a NSDictionary object that holds data converted from some JSON object.

My issue is some of the numbers are stored as strings and others stored as ints.  Ie within the NSDictionary, the number may either be of type NSString or NSNumber.  Somehow, I have to convert the numbers so they always return an NSNumber.

This is the solution I've come up with so far:

```
#import "Convert.h"
@implementation Convert
+(NSNumber *)toInteger:(NSObject *)object {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        return (NSNumber *) object;
    }
    else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {

        // Create number formatter
        NSNumberFormatter *formatInt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatInt setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

        // return formatted number
        return [formatInt numberFromString:(NSString *) object];
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
@end
```

In action:

```
NSNumber *myint;
myint = [Convert toInteger:[dict valueForKeyPath:@"myobj.numberAsString"]];
myint = [Convert toInteger:[dict valueForKeyPath:@"myobj.numberAsInteger"]];
```

This works, but it seems very long winded and not very cheap.  Is there another way that I haven't considered?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that you always read your numbers as integers, I presume that your strings only hold integers.

In that case you can use a common method implemented in both `NSNumber` and `NSString`: `integerValue`. This will save you from calls to `isKindOfClass:` and heavy branching. Object-oriented programming like it is 1989!

Goes like this:

```
NSNumber *myNumber = @([myStringOrNumber integerValue]);
```

The cost of this operation is that it will convert objects that already are numbers to other (but equivalent) number objects<sup>*</sup>, so take that into consideration. A small performance/simplicity trade-off.

<sub>* Except for some optimisation applied to the `NSNumber` class so the lowest-value integer numbers are implemented with a single instance for each of the values covered. In that case the line of code shown above will produce exactly the same object after the detour around `integerValue` and the `NSNumber` constructor.</sub>

Comment: Thanks mate! worked like a charm! You are correct in your assumption. I knew there had to be a simpler way.

Comment: Thanks for this. Wrapping the result in `@()` just resolved a cryptic error for me: "Sending 'float' to parameter of incompatible type 'id _Nullable'"

Answer (score 2):

Both NSNumber and NSString respond to the methods `-intValue` which returns an int. You can therefore do something like:

```
NSNumber *myNumber = @([[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"key.path"] intValue]); // using modern Objective-C syntax
```